# How to properly delete a test publication?

Tags: 2011

We created a test publication a while ago. I want to delete it but find this error message. What is the best way to get rid of a publication no longer needed?

> It is not possible to delete a Publication that contains published
>   items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to remove all its references and dependencies before you can delete it.

- Unpublish everything that you have published from this publication considering all the Publication Targets -
- See the blueprinting hierarchy, and update if this test publication is a parent of any publication - You need to update the child publication's blueprinting so that this test publication is no longer a parent of it

After doing above two steps, try to delete and if you still face problem, share the message.

Comment: Click on the publication, then: Right-Click -> Publishing -> UnPublish. This should unpublish everything that was published from this publication to whatever targets you configured to use it.

Comment: Thank you, Nuno! It works like a charm. I am glad that it is so easy.

Comment: FYI, in a later version, specifically 2013 SP1, you can *decommission* a publication target via the API. TOM.NET has `PublishEngine.DecommissionPublicationTarget` and the Core Service uses `DecommissionPublicationTarget`. This would also let you delete a publication in case there are issues with unpublishing.